# Cases when the error can occur - "Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"

Tags: java, spring, autowired, circular-dependency

I am getting this error -Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
Possible suspect is this autowiring in my code :

```
@Configuration
public class Bean1 {

  @Autowired
  private Bean3 bean3;
  @Autowired
  private Bean2 bean2;
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class Bean2 {

  @Autowired
  private Bean3 bean3;
}
```

Can this cause circular dependency and how ?

---

Edit : Adding the fix that worked for me. But seeking the reason why it worked..

After I made the autowiring of Bean3 lazy in Bean1, the error disappeared. But I can't understand why?

```
@Configuration
public class Bean1 {

  @Autowired
  @Lazy
  private Bean3 bean3;
  @Autowired
  private Bean2 bean2;
}
```

Adding the actual code of beans:
Bean1- DbConfig
Bean2- FindUser
Bean3- DocumentClient

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Database;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentCollection;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.config.AbstractDocumentDbConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.config.DocumentDBConfig;
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class DbConfig extends AbstractDocumentDbConfiguration {

  @Value("${db}")
  private String database;

  @Value("${key}")
  private String databaseURI;

  @Value("${someValue}")
  private String databaseKey;

  @Autowired
  private DocumentClient documentClient;

  @Override
  public DocumentDBConfig getConfig() {
    return DocumentDBConfig.builder(databaseURI, databaseKey, database).build();
  }

  public DocumentCollection getTodoCollection(String collectionName) {
    return documentClient
        .queryCollections("tst",
            "SELECT * FROM r WHERE r.id='" + collectionName + "'", null)
        .getQueryIterable().toList().get(0);
  }

  private Database getDb() {
    return null;
  }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.Document;
import com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.DocumentClient;
@Service
public class FindUser {


  @Autowired
  private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Lazy
  @Autowired
  private DocumentClient documentClient;

  @Autowired
  private DbConfig document;


  public String doSomething(String customerId) {
         return "something";
}}
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
<azure.version>2.1.2</azure.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-documentdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.everit.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.everit.json.schema</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Actuator for monitoring -->
        <!-- Google code formatter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
            <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber Dependency for java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: No, there is no circular dependency there. Even if you did have a circular dependency, it can only cause an error if you use *constructor injection*, and since you're not, it'll never fail for that reason.

Comment: *"After I made the autowiring of Bean3 lazy in **Bean2**"* Except the code you've shown has made it lazy in **Bean1**.

Comment: I meant Bean1, Sorry about the typo.  Code is correct.

Comment: Why `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`? The `application.properties` file is a built-in property source, so it's already in the environment. --- Given that, why `@Configuration`, and not a plain `@Component`? --- Also, your original Bean1 and Bean2 are both `@Configuration`, but your real `FindUser` (aka Bean2) is `@Service`, not `@Configuration`. --- `@Configuration` classes are very special to Spring, so that can make a big difference. Next time please be *accurate*, so we don't all waste our time.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no [circular dependency](https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring) there.

Dependency hierarchy is:

```
Bean1 ──> Bean2 ──┐
  │               ↓
  └───────────> Bean3
```

Even if you did have a circular dependency, it can only cause an error if you use *constructor injection*, and since you're using *field injection*, it'll never fail for that reason.

Comment: I got it. But this code seems to be the culprit. I am getting this “Is there an unresolvable circular reference?” on running my application. When I am using @Lazy with the Bean3 autowiring in Bean1 is seems to be working fine .. no error coming. Why is this happening?

Comment: @javaGroup456 Maybe your problem is because of something in Bean3, but since you haven't shown Bean3, we cannot know what that might be. If we assume the lack of showing it is because it has no dependencies, we have tried to reproduce your issue, but cannot do it, so please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you want further help.

Comment: I have attached the actuals code for the beans under Question. They might not compile at your end since they need some other classes and dependencies to work fine.

Comment: @javaGroup456 And once again you don't show Bean3, aka `DocumentClient`, which might actually be the culprit. Are you sure you want us to help, given that you continue to not provide the relevant information we need to help you?

Comment: DocumentClient is  a bean provided by the microsoft Azure library. Its there in the import statements. I added the dependencies so that  people can import it and  this library class can be checked out.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have circular dependency the case which you defined. As mentioned by @Andreas, this is one way of dependency not circular.

The circular is dependency is like,

```
@Configuration
public class Bean2 {

  @Autowired
  private Bean3 bean3;

}
```

And

```
@Configuration
public class Bean3 {

  @Autowired
  private Bean2 bean2;
}
```

This kind of example is of type of circular dependency.

There are ways to avoid this, like using of @Autowire on setter method of the object or use @Lazy on object. By this one object is created at the time of application loading and one is at the time of requirement.

Hope this help.

Comment: I used @Lazy and now its working why, but I can't seem to understand why.. Can you help me this.

Comment: I used @Lazy and now its working why, but I can't seem to understand why.. Can you help me this.

Comment: You get more information about @Lazy over here. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Make sure to have the Bean3 in the context, for instances by using `Component` annotation.

```
@Component
public class Bean3 {}
```